# Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized 32 - Could not authenticate you error

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am trying to get tweets data of a specific hashtags from a specific time frame. but while running the code i get the following error.

```
Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
32 - Could not authenticate you
```

The following is my code snippet.

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
              q="#fruit -filter:retweets",
              lang="en",
              since="2020-05-20").items(50)
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet)
```

I have my API keys, just did not share it here.

Comment: You might be getting this error because you are not allowed to run this search. Different Twitter accounts have different access levels to the available APIs, for some you have to pay a premium to access them. Check to what APIs you have access based on your account type. Have you run this query before? If you have then you might have reached your daily quota.

Comment: This might not b a code issue. Instead, an authentication issue. Checkout below link
https://twittercommunity.com/t/errors-message-could-not-authenticate-you-code-32/1223